# Получение адреса любого элемента массива символов

Tags: c++, массивы, строки, символы

Я создаю массив *символов*. Так `const char *str = "Hello";`  , так `char str[] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' };` или так `char str[] = "Hello";`  **Как получить адрес любого элемента массива?** Чтобы получить адрес нулевого элемента я пробывал `cout << &str << endl;`, но получаю я, наверное, адрес, где лежит указатель, или нет? Для первого варианта объявления массива можно сказать, что я получаю адрес указателя, а для остальных нет. С массивами символов всё не так, как с обычными статическими или динамическими, какие-то другие записи. Когда я записываю cout << &str[1] << endl; то получаю массив, без какой-либо буквы. Это, видимо, какая-то ложная запись, которая не работает. Решение вопроса предлагать только на c++.

Comment: `cout << (void*)&str[1] << endl;` Иначе вы выводите `char*`, а он выводится как строка, а не как указатель.

Comment: @Harry Есть ли ещё какие-нибудь варианты записи?  Как эта запись работает? Именно (void*)

Comment: В первом случае `str` и есть адрес нулевого элемента. адрес любого следующего получается прибавлением индекса `str + 1` и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Для первого варианта объявления массива можно сказать, что я получаю адрес указателя

В первом варианте вы объявляете указатель, не массив. Поэтому да, адрес указателя.

> Чтобы получить адрес нулевого элемента я пробывал `cout << &str << endl;`, но получаю я, наверное, адрес, где лежит указатель, или нет?

Нет, в случаях (2) и (3) вы получаете адрес всего массива. `&` - одна из немногих вещей, которая **не** вызывает неявного преобразования массива в указатель на первый элемент.

Этот адрес своим значением совпадает с адресом первого элемента, но отличается от него типом: `char (*)[6]` ("указатель на массив размера `6` из `char`") против `char *` ("указатель на `char`").

> С массивами символов всё не так, как с обычными статическими или динамическими, какие-то другие записи. Когда я записываю `cout << &str[1] << endl;` то получаю массив, без какой-либо буквы.

Дело не в массивах символов, они такие же как любые другие массивы. Дело в `cout`, который сделан так, что считает `char *` указателем на начало строки и печатает как строку.

> Это, видимо, какая-то ложная запись, которая не работает

Нуу, она работает, в том смысле что она печатает строку начиная с n-ого символа. Если это то, что вам нужно, то почему нет.

Как подсказали в комментариях, чтобы отучить `cout` печатать `char *` как строку, можно сделать `std::cout << (void*)&str[1] << '\n';`.

> Как эта запись работает? Именно (void*)

Она меняет тип указателя с `char *` на `void *`, а значение не меняет. Это называется "явное приведение типа", или "каст" ("cast", а точнее "C-style cast").

Такой тип `cout` уже не считает строкой, и печатает как число.

> Есть ли ещё какие-нибудь варианты записи?

`static_cast<const void *>(&str[1])`, `reinterpret_cast<const void *>(&str[1])`. Второй вариант мне нравится больше.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128518/discussion-on-answer-by-holyblackcat------).